# PySpark to pandas DataFrame error: objecthas no attribute 'dtype'

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I have been trying different ways and configurations now to use `.toPandas()` to create a `pandas` DataFrame on which I can perform regular Python commands from my PySpark DataFrame. However, I keep getting this issue:

```
/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/pandas/conversion.py:145: UserWarning: toPandas attempted Arrow optimization because 'spark.sql.execution.arrow.pyspark.enabled' is set to true, but has reached the error below and can not continue. Note that 'spark.sql.execution.arrow.pyspark.fallback.enabled' does not have an effect on failures in the middle of computation.
  'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'dtype'
  warnings.warn(msg)
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'dtype'
```

Does anyone know how I can solve this problem? One of the things I tried is running:

```
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.execution.arrow.enabled", "false")
```

However, this, just like many other things, doesn't work. I hope someone can help me with this! By the way, I am working in the Databricks environment, and the command I'm running is:

```
pd_flights = flights.select("*").toPandas()
```

UPDATE: result of `df.printSchema()`:

```
flight_id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- flight_direction: string (nullable = true)
 |-- service_type: string (nullable = true)
 |-- flight_designator: string (nullable = true)
 |-- flight_number: string (nullable = true)
 |-- callsign: string (nullable = true)
 |-- scheduled_datetime: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- connecting_flight_designator: string (nullable = true)
 |-- airport_iata_codes: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- airline_name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- airport_names: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- country_number: long (nullable = true)
 |-- eu_category: string (nullable = true)
 |-- safe_town_indicator: boolean (nullable = true)
 |-- sibt: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- aibt: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- sobt: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- aibt: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- tsat: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- aircraft_name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- aircraft_registration: string (nullable = true)
 |-- ramp: string (nullable = true)
 |-- ramp_previous: string (nullable = true)
 |-- seats: long (nullable = true)
 |-- actual_total_pax: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- handler_apron: string (nullable = true)
 |-- occupancy_rate: double (nullable = false)
```

Comment: Could you do `flights.printSchema()`?  You might have a column that has issue converting to Pandas or might have duplicated columns.

Comment: I just added it! Haven't been able to solve it in the mean time.

Comment: There are 2 `aibt` columns, this could cause issues. Could you try renaming or drop 1 column?  You have to do it where duplication is introduced (likely at `join`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to use `dtypes` instead of `dtype`.

`dtypes` will get us the types for the columns on the dataframe.

**Example:**

```
df=spark.createDataFrame([('1','ABC','2022-03-01 08:55:29.423'),('2','DEF','2022-03-01 08:55:29.423'),
                         ('3','GHI','2022-03-01 08:55:29.423'),('1','ABC','2022-02-28 12:43:17.142'),('2','DEF','2022-02-27 23:31:26.777'),
                         ('3','GHI','2022-02-18 06:17:11.534 '),
                         ],['col1','col2','modified_time'])

print(df.dtypes)
#[('col1', 'string'), ('col2', 'string'), ('modified_time', 'string')]

#pandas dataframe 
df1= df.toPandas()
print(df1.dtypes)
#col1             object
#col2             object
#modified_time    object
#dtype: object
```

Comment: Hi, my issue is not that I want to know the dtypes. It just returns the error.

Comment: I solved the problem. There were multiple entries of "aibt"